# display multiple row for one record in jqgrid

Tags: java, jquery

hi i want to display the multiple row for single record in jqgrid. For example if a grid has 10 columns such as c1,c2,c3...c10 and values such as va1,va2,va3....,va10 and vb1,vb2,vb3....,vb10 and so on. it should display as,

----------------------              ->Headers

### |c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|

### |c6|c7|c8|c9|c10|

----------------------          ->value1

### |va1|va2|va3|va4|va5|

### |va6|va7|va8|va9|va10|

----------------------         ->value2

### |vb1|vb2|vb3|vb4|vb5|

### |vb6|vb7|vb8|vb9|vb10|

---

.                              ->value3
.
.

please help me

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: What have above is not a table. You do not have a clear assignment of each cell to a header. Or in other words: each value has multiple headers…

Comment: I think this cant be implemented using jqgrid.